# Margins of an input field will not get 0px from top of div

Tags: html, css, twig, margin

I have an input field (id: "ordersearch") and a button (id: "searchbutton") in a form within a div.

The problem is that despite trying, I can't seem to get the top margin of the input field and the button to be 0px.

See this screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9wQW.png)

I've tried clearfix but to no avail. Left of that div there's another div where the top margin to a button is succesfully set to 0px. So it does not seem inheritance of any css. The code of the part of the template to which it applies is here (it's a symfony2 twig template):

```html
<div class="span-24 last topactions">
    <div class="span-16"><a href="{{ path('orders_new_empty') }}" class="fbutton button-success fbutton-inline fbutton-small">{{ 'order.new' | trans }}</a></div>
    <div class="span-7 last searchbox"><form action="{{ path('orders') }}" method="post"><input type="text" name="search" id="ordersearch" class="searchfield" placeholder="{{ 'searchplaceholder' | trans }}"><input class="fbutton fbutton-inline fbutton-small" type="submit" value="{{ 'search' | trans }}" id="searchbutton"></form></div>
    <div class="prepend-20 span-4 last filter textright">
        <select id="filter">
            <option value="all">{{ 'order.filter.all' | trans }}</option>
            <option value="orders" {% if 'orders' in filtername %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'order.filter.orders' | trans }}</option>
            <option value="payed" {% if 'payed' in filtername %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'order.filter.payedorders' | trans }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the relevant css of this part of the template. I've set some borders to see where the margins are. These borders will be set to zero eventually:

```css
.topactions {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0px;
}
.topactions .span-17 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.searchbox {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}
.searchbox form {
    /* margin-bottom: -6px; */ 
}
.searchbox .autocomplete-suggestions {
    right: 0px;
    width: auto !important;
    text-align: left;
}
.filter {
    margin-top: 3px
}
searchfield,
.searchfield {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 160px;
}
.last {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.span-7 {
    width: 270px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.span-16 {
    width: 630px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.span-24 {
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#form .totoplink {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
#form .totopheader {
    margin-top: 40px
}
#form label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 4px;
   }
#form .subfield label {
    width: 110px;
    border: none;
}
#form label.textarealabel {
    padding-bottom: 105px
}
#form input,
#formemail input {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    }
#form input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
}
#form div {
    /*position: relative; */ 
}
.fbutton {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 37px;
}
.fbutton i {
    line-height: 37px
}
.fbutton:active,
.fbutton:active i {
    line-height: 40px
}
.fbutton-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any margin on your text input http://jsfiddle.net/dj3fp15s/

Comment: Too much code. Half this CSS clearly isn't related to the problem you're asking about (there's a load of stuff to do with colors, transitions, and fonts in the code you've dumped). We expect *minimal* reproducible examples in debugging questions here; please try to slim down your code to *the shortest possible* snippet that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Sexy Turnip, no beacuse they didn't help solving this iisue so I've not kept them in my code.

Comment: @Mark Amery, thanks for pointing that out. I've removed all the css for colors, radiusses, shadows and other formatting options. And also added a screenshot. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the margin to zero by adding the `style="margin:0px"` in the twig template and that fixed the issue. Putting that `margin:0px;` in the stylesheet does not have the same effect for the element, so somewhere in the stylesheets(s) that setting is overruled again. Still don't know where that is or why, but I'll find out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adjusting one of these:

```
.fbutton {
    line-height: 37px;
}
.fbutton i {
    line-height: 37px
}
.fbutton:active,
.fbutton:active i {
    line-height: 40px
}
.fbutton-inline {
    vertical-align: middle; /* remove or add to textbox? */
}
```

it would also be helpful if you could set this up on jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you are looking for, by simply adding

```
.searchbox {
padding: 0;
}

#ordersearch {
border: none;
}
```

at the end of your styles.